# Android Emulator Accelerator: –b failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found

Tags: android, emulation, intel, haxm

I'm using macbook air. I'm try to use Intel HAXM to accelerate android emulator. I've installed Intel HAXM successfully without any error. After installation, I ran the following command:

```
kextstat | grep intel
```

and got the following result:

```
131    0 0xffffff7f82319000 0x11000    0x11000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (1.0.8) <7 5 4 3 1>
```

Now, if I try to start it, I get error.

Start command: 
    sudo kextload –b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm

I get the following error:

```
/Users/farhadrubel/–b failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).

/Users/farhadrubel/com.intel.kext.intelhaxm failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
```

Can anybody please tell me, how can I solve this issue and integrate the accelerator with android emulator?

Comment: By the way, I'm using Macbook air 2013, OS X 10.9.4 (Mavericks)

Answer (score 0):

Are you currently running any other virtualization software like VirtualBox, sometimes they could be interrupting proper functioning of HAXM. Here is [detailed instructions for installing and debugging of intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x). I would try a fresh reboot, and load/start the haxm.